# Get a string in fprintf output to display all characters

Tags: matlab, printf

I'm trying to write a matlab code to generate some kind of result page in a textfile but there seems to be some basic knowledge gap here (I'm new to matlab). So the thing that has me confused is how matlab handles strings. I thought I could create a vector full of strings e.g. `SampleNr = ['sample1','sample2'];` and later take that vector and print out to the file one specific element, e.g. `fprintf(fid, '%s', SampleNr(i));` but when I run this I only get the character in position `i` in the string instead of the whole string. As I said this is most likely me misunderstanding this concept, and searches on the mathworks site haven't made this clearer to me so I seek the collective wisdom of stackexchange. A MWE would be:

```
 SampleNr = ['sample1','sample2'];
 sprintf('%s', SampleNr(2))
```

A method to get the whole string would be appreciated, but I would also like to have this confusion cleared up if possible, so in the future I can work confidently with strings in matlab. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In matlab a string is an array of characters, so when you write `['sample1','sample2']`, it concatanates 2 strings to make one string `'sample1sample2'`.

To be clear, when you write a string `'sample'`, it is stored like this: `['s','t','r','i','n','g']`

To do what you want, you need to use cells:

```
SampleNr = {'sample1','sample2'}
sprintf('%s', SampleNr{2})
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains alot :)